# Asynchronous processing using shell_exec is not possible

Tags: python, php

I am trying to call a python script asynchronously in php.
I am using shell_exec and the call is successful, but php waits for the python script to finish processing.
How can I get php to exit without waiting for the python script to finish processing?

I will present the script that I created.

- sample.php

```php
<?php
/* cf. https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/207/how-to-execute-a-shell-command-using-php-without-await-for-the-result-asynchronous-in-linux-and-windows-environments */

$time = -hrtime(true);

/* call python script */
$comando = `python run.py`;
shell_exec($comando." > /dev/null &");

/* I would expect the elapsed time to be less than 1 second, but it shows a time that exceeds 5 seconds, the execution time of the python script!!!!!! */
$end = sprintf('%f', ($time + hrtime(true))/1e+9);
echo $end;

?>
```

- run.py

```py
import time

def run():

    # do anything ...
    time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Any advice would be appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause.

The command that was supposed to be written as a string was written in backquotes and was being executed there.

The correct way is to use single quotes.

- incorrect (use "`")

```php
... snip ...
$comando = `python run.py`;
... snip ...
```

- correct (use "'")

```php
... snip ...
$comando = 'python run.py';
... snip ...
```